# Discrete mathmatic how many ways

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 13 people be placed at 13 (distinguishable) chairs around
a round table, without Suzy and Johnny (which is among the 13) sits next
each other?

I am confused should i use bioniomial theorem or?

Comment: Do the problem with 12 "people", one of which is the two (Suzy,Johnny) thought of as one "person", which afterwards goes in one of the two possible orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $13$ ways to seat the first person, $12$ for the second, etc. So a priori we have $13!$ ways to seat everyone. However we have included the illegal arrangements where John and Suzy are next to each other. We should count the cases where they are together and subtract that from $13!$.

We can place Suzy in any of $13$ chairs. Then John must be either to her left or right, so he has $2$ possibilities. Then there are $11!$ ways to seat the rest of the people.

There will be $13!-13\cdot 2\cdot 11!$ possibilities.

Comment: Why must we subtract from 13! Elliot G??

Comment: We counted $13!$ ways to seat them if we ignore the requirement that John and Suzy can't be together. So we count the number of "illegal" arrangements and delete them from the total number of ways to seat everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution:
We first choose where Suzy sits, of which there are $13$ possibilities.

Then we choose where Johnny sits. Johnny can't sit where Suzy is sitting and he can't sit to the left or right of Suzy, so there are $10$ possibilities.

Then we seat the remaining $11$ people, of which there are $11$! ways.

Thus, there are $13 * 10 * 11!$ possibilities.